# Is there a way we can provide maxAllowedContentLength without using web.config in .net core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

How to provide maxAllowedContentLength without using web.config

```
 <security>
          <requestFiltering>
              <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
          </requestFiltering>
      </security>
```

Comment: `web.config` affects IIS *only*, not ASP.NET Core. If you deploy to IIS, you need to configure it

Comment: @Hema S, any update? Does my reply help you?

Comment: I'm running NET 7 host which is IIS Express as a reversed proxy on top of Kestrel. I cannot upload more than 28-30MB despite the maxAllowedContentLength set in applicationhost.config. Don't know why is it ignored and what to do... I've also tried to use some attributes on Upload method to enlarge the Request limits. But in vain.

Answer (score 1):

According to the asp.net core [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#application-configuration), you could find we could try to set `MaxRequestBodySize` if you aren't host the application on IIS.

If you want to host the application on the IIS, you could only set the `maxAllowedContentLength` in web.config, since the maxAllowedContentLength is happened before the `MaxRequestBodySize`.

More details, you could refer to below description.

MaxRequestBodySize is used to get or set the max request body size for the HttpRequest.

Note that IIS itself has the limit maxAllowedContentLength which will be processed before the MaxRequestBodySize set in the IISServerOptions. Changing the MaxRequestBodySize won't affect the maxAllowedContentLength. To increase maxAllowedContentLength, add an entry in the web.config to set maxAllowedContentLength to a higher value. For more details, see Configuration.